# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста! Нужна ли запятая после "практически"? Это наречие, и при другом порядке слов запятой бы не требовалось, но здесь оно как будто выступает в роли вводного слова...

Практически брака у нас нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Практически - нареч. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

Дополнение

> Слово "Практически" является наречием и не выделяется или отделяется запятыми.[ГРАМОТА.РУ](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=582.ss3Nx4TrRVm0DxawzKvysKBi14LNsKkfSMNiSHL0qPzh0gERFwIA1nJHTPNtxae2BppNVIWo1y993C5hYOuRxA8kJvc_nAGw3gq5LYb5Uf_ptO3u9M8IWeXNA8kLD8x2t9f7EBG7-q3xRGcoOx5537qPV8A5O1lpVxfDvz02mD3XithmJZu-DoXUNMlfdB77.79c09eadcd55ab85988c532b196f9aaa6d7ef227&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsMCv5TMMN9UTQSQbnFqxRfy1qNK6_no62JEFvW2UZjTibK6ICh6iYNbEoR8c-LynPH2mh_zXKXjId5KWWVUpYz6M63Bbn8WICgbSRHSP-yZzYz9P2iJ16FYMBUKysixnZSx7slWDV0JEgJVS82anG2UiLpKUPFdTG9syyst5OE2ODOw9KJ6sq37kB4T1vtV1fc8KXilUyJuH2wBrmLMUDhWbVc-74o5og&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBEZktJbU8ybXhCM3hINFFfRkxMVjRDTTdORUZYeDB1Y3paMmRiWVdaNTVNVk5FemJFUUs3dU11V3hDQjhSdnN5YjV5RjlzeHV0ZHBRTThhaDZwa1NFSHh4c2Nxd2thOFU2ZlBfLUJQcUdyaw&b64e=2&sign=0e05f8c33b28e845eb9a873d87e679e0&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1422355410400&mc=4.428137663249133)  [Поставь запятую правильно. Вводные.](http://writercenter.ru/blog/grammar/19475.html)
> Если бы слово практически могло бы употребляться в роли вводного, об этом написали бы.

Answer (score 0):

*"...но здесь оно как будто выступает в роли вводного слова..."*

Да, в роли вводного. Если необходимо сохранить именно этот порядок слов, что-нибудь -- запятую или тире -- после *практически* следовало бы поставить. Что именно -- можно решить только при наличии контекста. Скорее всего, понадобится запятая.

Comment: Остановилась на варианте без запятой, поэтому ответ снимаю.

Answer (score 0):

ПРАКТИЧЕСКИ, нареч.

1.В практическом отношении, на практике (1-2 зн.). Идея исследована п. и теоретически. Осуществить замысел п. П. решить проблему. Ознакомиться с материалами п.

2.По существу, по сути дела. Работа п. завершена. Собрались п. все. П. всё осталось по-прежнему. П. оба проекта не годны.

Итак, наречие имеет два значения, в первом из них это только необособленное обстоятельство. А вот во втором оно может быть вводным словом, только структура предложения должна быть соответствующей.

Практически брака у нас нет. - Брака у нас практически  нет. Не думаю, что здесь стоит обособлять наречие. Перестановка связана, скорее, с актуальным членением предложения.

Для обособления нужна большая распространенность, например: Практически, мы про оба проекта можем сказать, что они совершенно не готовы. Поэтому в реальных текстах обособление встречается редко.

Answer (score 0):

Это предложение односоставное, безличное, сказуемое слово "нет"; нет (как?) практически (всегда, совсем) - наречие, которое в этом предложении обстоятельство.

Comment: Пожалуйста, закончите Вашу мысль. Напишите, какой из этого следует вывод в контексте заданного вопроса.